# Why are root vegetables (potatoes and carrots) forbidden when they are sanctioned?

Tags: food, diet

Root vegetables such as potatoes and carrots cannot be eaten because they cause injury to the vegetables, unlike non-root vegetables.

However, how are these prohibited when root vegetables are permitted for sannyasis?

> [Gautama (3.26)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200559.html).—‘A hermit shall live in the forest **subsisting on roots** and fruits, practising austerities; he shall kindle the fire under the Śramaṇaka rules, he shall eat wildgrowing vegetables only.’

Comment: Just curious where is it mentioned root vegetables cannot be eaten? Thanks

Comment: I’ve been wondering possibility of avocados being grown in India. Wouldn’t the temperature and such be ok for that ? And so nutritious. Had no idea Portuguese (?) ppl brought over potatoes and before that potatoes weren’t part of Indian food. Learned that from another thread on here.

Comment: @Ketan Manusmriti bans consumption of onion, garlic, carrots, radish & mushroom. These vegetables, alongside Malabar spinach are considered to exert an influence similar to that of consuming meat. There is a lacunae regarding consumption of foreign-origin vegetables like potatoes, tomatoes, chillis, capsicum, pumpkin, corn & beans.

Comment: Thanks @AnubrataBit

Comment: @AnubrataBit Well said. And the lacunae is there because these vegetables were not known to ancient Indians during the time the Manusmriti was written.